# how to check speech recognition is supported by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website has `index.html` and `voice.html`.

If someone navigates to `voice.html`,they should redirect to `index.html` if voice recognition is not supported by the browser.

```
if (!code to check if voice recognition is not supported by the browser)
{
       redirect to index.html
}
```

I am using `annyang.js`.

If i open `voice.html`. From ***OPERA*** it should redirect to `index.html`. Because I think opera does not support voice recognition.

Comment: Your problem is not that you have a double negative.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @stark pardon. i did not get you

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should be able to handle the concerns.

```
if ('SpeechRecognition' in window || 'webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
  // speech recognition API supported
} else {
  // speech recognition API not supported

  //redirect to another page
  location.href = "index.html";

}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have much browser support. The code fails in chrome even though `webkitSpeechRecognition` is supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Clint yes it works in chrome only. Have modified the script to better handle the check for chrome. The document you had shared has all details regarding the compatibility concerns.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you need to do for detection, depends on what exactly you mean by voice recognition. If you mean Chrome's `x-webkit-speech`, this should work:

```
if (document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech === undefined) {
    location.href = "index.html";
}
```

Comment: i am using annyang.js. if i open voice.html from OPERA it should redirect to index.html because i think opera doesnot support voice recognition

Comment: @sky I think it would be a good idea to explain in your question description which voice recognition you're using `annyang.js` we aren't mind readers so we don't know what will or will not be supported if we don't know what it is you're using... Detailed question is the key to a solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/41bcd475d863a20e456d3ecbb988e3764625c198/annyang.js#L32-L35) you can just run a truthy check for `annyang`:

```js
if (!annyang) {
    location.href = 'index.html';
}
```